# Order queryset by the number of foreign key instances in a Django field

Tags: python, django, count

I am trying to return the objects relating to a through table which counts the number of reactions on a blog post.

I have an Article model, Sentiment model and Reactions model. The sentiment is simply a 1 or 2, `1` representing `like` and `2` for `dislike`. On the frontend users can react to an article and their reactions are stored in a Reactions table.

```
Reactions model

class Reaction(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='article_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sentiment = models.ForeignKey(Sentiment, related_name='sentiment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to find the 2 most liked articles so I have written a view to handle the GET request

```
views.py

class MostPopularView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Reaction.objects.annotate(num_likes = Count('sentiment_id')).order_by('num_likes')
    serializer_class = MostPopularSerializer
```

and a serializer to transform the data

```
serializers.py

class MostPopularSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
        )
        model = Article
```

As the code stands now, I'm getting a response

```
<QuerySet [<Reaction: d745e09b-5685-4592-ab43-766f47c73bef San Francisco Bay 1>, <Reaction: d745e09b-5685-4592-ab43-766f47c73bef The Golden Gate Bridge 1>, <Reaction: dd512e6d-5015-4a70-ac42-3afcb1747050 San Francisco Bay 1>, <Reaction: dd512e6d-5015-4a70-ac42-3afcb1747050 The Golden Gate Bridge 2>]>
```

Showing `San Francisco Bay` has 2 likes and `The Golden Gate Bridge` has 1 like and 1 dislike.

I've tried multiple methods to get the correct response including filtering by `sentiment=1` but can't get any further than this.
What I'm looking for is a way to count the number of `sentiment=1` fields which correspond to each article `id` and order them in descending order, so most liked at the top.

### Edit

I've rethought my approach although I have not yet found a solution

1. Filter Reaction table by `sentiment=1`
2. Order by count of `article_id`
3. Serialize with `MostPopularSerializer`

I changed the `View` to be a `ModelViewSet`

```
class MostPopularView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    articles = Reaction.objects.filter(sentiment=1).annotate(num_likes = Count('article_id')).order_by('num_likes')[:4]
    # queryset = Article.objects.filter(id=articles['article_id'])
#Doesn't work by hypothetically what I'm thinking
    for article in articles:
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(id=article['article_id'])
    serializer_class = MostPopularSerializer
```

And the serializer to be a `ModelSerializer`

```
class MostPopularSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'tags',
        )
        model = Article
```

and an updated URL for good measure
`path('popular', views.MostPopularView.as_view({'get': 'list'}))`

Any tips on achieving these steps would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to use the `Reaction` as queryset, you use the `Article` as queryset, so:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When


class MostPopularView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.annotate(
        sentiment=Sum(
            Case(
                When(article_id__sentiment_id=1, then=Value(1)),
                When(article_id__sentiment_id=2, then=Value(-1)),
            )
        )
    ).order_by('-sentiment')
    serializer_class = MostPopularSerializer
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `user`, instead of <s>`user_id`</s>.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Reaction`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`user`</s> relation to `reactions`.

Comment: Thanks Willem! this got it working, just as a note I had to use the `ModelViewSet` as `RetrieveAPIView` required a `pk` argument. I'll alter the `ForeignKey` names and rethink `related_name` fields. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I solved a simular Problem a different way.
For me I wanted to sort a queryset of Person by how often the Country was used.

I added a property to the Model

```
class Country(models.Model):
    .
    .
    def _get_count(self):
        count = len(Person.objects.filter(country=self.id))

        return count or 0

    count = property(_get_count)
```

In the View I have this queryset

```
qs = sorted(Country.objects.all(), key=lambda country: country.count*-1)
```

I needed to use python sorted because the django qs.order_by can not sort by property.
The *-1 is for descending order